# How multi host docker containers and java application static variables work?

Tags: java, docker, static

Let's say I have a `static` variable `counter` in my java application, that counts every hit on a website.

Something like below:

```
int static counter = 0;
```

Now this java application is running inside a docker container deployed on multiple hosts that is `H1` and `H2`.

Now, let say the application running inside the container of host `H1` has counter value updated to say **1**, now ideally this value **1** should also be reflected on an application that is running in a container deployed in a host `H2`

I am assuming this because same application is running on different hosts.

How docker achieve that ?

Comment: ... what? Sorry, the questoin is unclear. What exactly is `H1` and `H2`? First you say those are hosts, then you say that one is a container and the other is a variable. And what query are you talking about. Please [edit] the post and clarify.

Comment: @Turing85 Done, question updated, actually I wanted to know how docker maintains the state of in memory variable or you can say in memory cache for an application that is running on two different hosts.

Comment: Docker - on itself -does not do this and has no built-in solution for this. This - in general - is a separate concern and should thus be handled separately. Just imagine that one container goes down for some time and comes back up again. How should it get the "current value" for this counter? Snychronizing the value over multiple instances is also non-trivial and might not scale well. The easiest solution is most probably a central database in which the state is kept.

Comment: To share values between containers, a database or something like Redis is often used.

Comment: So what I understand is if we are deploying our app in a multi host environment, then static keyword of java make no sense and we are not supposed to use it

Comment: It can make sense, but it's not shared among containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's say I have a static variable...

You will get inconsistent behavior in a variety of environments.  This even goes back to classic old-school when-XML-was-trendy Java application servers; even then it was known that a static variable could be incorrectly shared between instances of the application, or not shared when you expected it to be.

> ...deployed on multiple hosts...

Each host runs its own separate copy of the application.  The static variable is not shared.  If you ever restart the application or deploy it on a different host, the static variable's value is lost, and the next instance of the application will start over at zero.

None of this has anything to do with Docker.  In some ways Docker makes the problem a little worse; if you're using a clustered container system like Kubernetes, it's very easy to have multiple copies of the application, it's very routine to delete and recreate them, and sometimes the cluster will delete the container under you.

The solution to this is the same, whether you're using containers or not: store any data that needs to be shared in a data store outside any particular instance of the process.  Anything that needs a life span longer than an individual request probably needs to be persisted in some sort of database or persistent cache.  If you're in the Spring ecosystem, the [Spring Data](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data) subproject has support for a variety of data stores; even if not, looking at the systems it supports can give you an idea of the range of possible databases.  For just a simple request counter, [Redis](https://redis.io) is often a straightforward simple-to-deploy option.